# Connected $T_3$ space

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I wanted to prove that a connected $T_3-$space containing atleast two points must be uncountable.

My attempt is as follows:
Let $X$ be a connected $T_3-$ space and let $x,y\in X$. Then there exist disjoint open sets $G,H$ containing $x$ and $y$ respectively. Since $X$ is connected, therefore, $X\neq G\cup H$. Thus $\exists z\in X$ such that $z\notin G\cup H$.

I couldn't proceed further. Please help.

Comment: See [here](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Connected_and_regular_Hausdorff_with_at_least_two_points_implies_uncountable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only proofs that I can see at the moment are indirect: suppose that $X$ is countable and $T_3$, and show that $X$ cannot be connected. A countable space is clearly Lindelöf, and it’s a standard basic result that a Lindelöf $T_3$-space is $T_4$, so $X$ is $T_4$ and therefore Tikhonov. Now let $x$ and $y$ be distinct points of $X$; since $X$ is Tikhonov, there is a continuous function $f:X\to[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. Now use the fact that $f[X]$ is countable to find disjoint non-empty open sets $U$ and $V$ in $X$ such that $U\cup V=X$.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott: Sir, can I argue as follows:

$f(X)$ is countable, so it is not connceted subset of $R$. This is a contradiction as $X$ is connected and $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @Anupam: Yes, you can do that, and get a proof by contradiction. I had something slightly different in mind, since I was assuming that $X$ is countable but not that $X$ is connected. Since $f[X]$ is countable, there is an $r\in(0,1)\setminus f[X]$, and $U=f^{-1}[(0,r)]$ and $V=f^{-1}[(r,1)}$ then have the properties that I mentioned in the last sentence of my answer.